# retrieve data from dynamic text boxes created with jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I'm creating text boxes using jquery.I want after that to get the data from text boxes and insert the answers in my table. This is my code for creating the text boxes.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

        var counter = 2;

        $("#addButton").click(function () {

            if (counter > 10) {
                alert("Only 10 textboxes allow");
                return false;
            }

            var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
      .attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);

            newTextBoxDiv.html('<label>Raspuns' + counter + ' : </label>' +
       '<input type="text" name="textbox'  + counter +
       '" id="textbox' + counter + '" value="" >' );

            newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");


            counter++;
        });

        $("#removeButton").click(function () {
            if (counter == 1) {
                alert("No more textbox to remove");
                return false;
            }

            counter--;

            $("#TextBoxDiv" + counter).remove();

        });


    });
```

How can I select the data from the textboxes? I'm using c# and it's a asp.net application

Comment: a small suggestion: use css classes in your elements to select them more easyly later

Answer (score 0):

use the Request object to see the posted values....

```
var x = HttpContext.Current.Request[name]
```

...guessing you are talking about using the inserted data in codebehind.

They are not otherwise reachable as e.g. Textbox1.Value or so..

They are not available to the page afterwards, as viewstate, but that might not be important to you

Comment: "name" being the name of my dynamic text box whici in my case has the name "textbox"?? if so how can i get all the values from the textboxes??

Comment: no - the na you give the inputs in the jquery: name="textbox' + counter  - so you will have to try  "textbox0", "textbox1", "textbox2", etc.. make a loop and test if the .Request['textbox#'] is not null for that counter value.